# How to eliminate the first characters of entries in a PySpark DataFrame column?

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

So I have a given PySpark DataFrame, say `df`, looking like below:

```py
df.show()
+--------------------+-------------------+
|              series|          value    |
+--------------------+-------------------+
|     XXXX-AAAA      |          1        |
|     XXXX-BB        |          2        |
|     XXXX-CCCCC     |          3        |
+--------------------+-------------------+
```

In the `series` column, I would like to get rid of the `XXXX-` substring (i.e. length of 5 characters), which is the same for each single entry of that column, thus obtaining the followind DataFrame, say `df2`:

```py
df2.show()
+--------------------+-------------------+
|              series|          value    |
+--------------------+-------------------+
|        AAAA        |          1        |
|        BB          |          2        |
|        CCCCC       |          3        |
+--------------------+-------------------+
```

I have tried to use the `substr` method but, as you can imagine, the challenge lies in the variability of the length of each entry in the `series` column. The code that I have tried is the following:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import length

df2 = df.withColumn('series_truncated', df.timestamp.substr(5, length(df.series)))
df2 = df2.drop('series')
df2 = df2.withColumnRenamed("series_truncated", "series")
df.show()
```

Together with the associated error:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-6585c018cd92> in <module>
      3 #print(length(df.series))
      4 #df_test.show()
----> 5 df = df.withColumn('series_truncated', df.timestamp.substr(15, length(df.series)))  # Eliminate the first 14 digits of the timestamp column
      6 
      7 #df_test = df.withColumn('length_series', length(df.series))

/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/column.py in substr(self, startPos, length)
    417                 .format(
    418                     startPos_t=type(startPos),
--> 419                     length_t=type(length),
    420                 ))
    421         if isinstance(startPos, int):

TypeError: startPos and length must be the same type. Got <class 'int'> and <class 'pyspark.sql.column.Column'>, respectively.
```

Does anyone know how this can be solved?

Many thanks in advance,

Marioanzas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df.withColumn('series', F.regexp_extract('series', 'XXXX-(.*)$', 1)).show()
+------+-----+
|series|value|
+------+-----+
|  AAAA|    1|
|    BB|    2|
| CCCCC|    3|
+------+-----+
```

Or

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df.withColumn('series', F.expr('substring(series, 6, length(series) - 5)')).show()
+------+-----+
|series|value|
+------+-----+
|  AAAA|    1|
|    BB|    2|
| CCCCC|    3|
+------+-----+
```

Note that the `substring` function in Pyspark API does not accept column objects as arguments, but the Spark SQL API does, so you need to use `F.expr` in the second method.

Comment: Hi @mck , thank you so much for your suggestion. Just for my understanding, what is the `6` in `substring(series, 6, length(series) - 5)` doing?

Comment: `6` defines the starting position of the substring.  Note that Spark SQL uses 1-based index for substring indexing.

Comment: Ah ok I see, undestood. What about `length(series) - 5` ? Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: That's the length of the substring that you want to extract. You need to subtract 5 for the first 5 chars.

Answer (score 1):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import substring, length, col, expr
df.withColumn('series',expr('substring(series, 6, length(series))'))
```

Comment: How about values like this `XXXX-AAAA-TTTT`? Also, `$` for column is specific to Spark Scala, use `col` for Pyspark.

Comment: Yep, I agree with @blackbishop , I can have instances when a column entry is something like `XXX-AAAA-TTTT`.

Comment: updated answer to accept `XXX-AAAA-TTTT` input

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [`right`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#right) function along with `lenght` to get the rightmost `length(series)-5` caracters from the string:

```
df.withColumn("series", expr("right(series, length(series)-5)")).show()

#+------+-----+
#|series|value|
#+------+-----+
#|  AAAA|    1|
#|    BB|    2|
#| CCCCC|    3|
#+------+-----+
```

Or simply [`replace`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#replace) `XXXX-` by empty string `''`:

```
df.withColumn("series", expr("replace(series, 'XXXX-', '')")).show()
```

Note however that replace will get rid of all `XXXX-` occurrences not only at the beginning of the string.

Comment: Hi @blackbishop , many thanks with your suggestion. Thinking a bit outside of the box, the trouble that I find with the second approach is that it is limited to the exclusive use of `XXXX-` as a prefix in each column entry. What if there was a possibility of having something different than `XXXX-`, like say `YYYY-` (assuming always a length of characters of 5.